# Disable cron jobs or cron daemon on Ubuntu 10.04 server in rescue mode

Tags: ubuntu, cron

I am trying to recover an Ubuntu 10.04 server in rescue mode and I want to stop cron jobs and/or cron daemon running on reboot. So far I have:

- Edited the cron files in /var/spool/cron/
- renamed /etc/init.d/cron to cron.disabled

but the cron jobs **still** run on a reboot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To stop CRON from running on any run level you can do the following:

```
 update-rc.d cron remove
```

When you renamed **cron** to **cron.disabled** in init.d, this will probably still work as the links are still active in all the run levels.

When you want CRON back as usual you can run.

```
update-rc.d cron defaults
```

If you run either command with -n (it will show you what it will do, but won't actually perform the action)

```
 update-rc.d -n cron remove
```

If using upstart you can try:

```
echo manual | sudo tee /etc/init/cron.override
```

Will put the Cron  service into manual mode, so it won't start the next time the server restarts. To put cron back into normal mode do

```
sudo rm /etc/init/cron.override
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me as on my host (Rackspace) rescue mode means you have to mount your filesystem in a completely different folder. So unless I chroot in that folder I can't use update-rc.d

Comment: Try using the manual command as above.